# Addthis Stumbleupon Button Style

Tags: addthis

I am using the following code to display stumbleupon button:

```
<a class="addthis_button_stumbleupon_badge" su:bdg:style="5"></a>
```

I want to render the stumbleupon button with `style ="5"`, however it displays the default style. I am not able to figure out how to solve this. For a demo please this page: http://loveaquote.com/topics/communication-quotes/

Comment: Two colons in an attribute name doesn't look valid to me. Can you point us to the Addthis or Stumbleupon documentation you're using for that attribute?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the addthis docs are wrong.

Try instead: `su:badge:style="5"`